# My first plot overlapping my second plot on nested for loop (Python/Plotly)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, plotly, nested-loops

I'm having a hard time understanding this nested for-loop problem, I want to make automated plot using the nested for-loop in plotly, but my first graph resulted from first loop overlapping my second graph

Here is my code

```
#Read all the well log data
paths = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join("well_contoh", "*.LAS")))
well_df = [0]*2
for i in range(len(paths)):
    well = lasio.read(paths[i])
    df = well.df()
    well_df[i] = df.reset_index()
well1, well2 = well_df #only 2 wells


#Automatic well log plots if any well log data comes in in the future
html_list = []
dataframe_well = {'Well 1F':well1, 'Well 2F':well2} #defining dataframe

wells = ['Well 1F','Well 2F'] #list of well for looping

#list of longitude and latitude for well 1 and well 2 respectively (a dummy coordinate)
Longitude = [96.083956, 96.356427]
Latitude = [5.456862, 5.328133]

#list of logs and their colors
logs = ['CALI', 'GR', 'RT', 'NPHI', 'RHOB', 'DT']
colors = ['black', 'green', 'red', 'royalblue', 'mediumaquamarine', 'goldenrod']

#plot
log_cols = np.arange(1,8)
logplot = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=len(logs), shared_yaxes = True, specs=[[{},{},{},{},{},{}]], 
                        horizontal_spacing=0.005)

for i in range(len(wells)):
    for j in range(len(logs)):
        if j == 2:
            logplot.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dataframe_well[wells[i]][logs[j]], y=dataframe_well[wells[i]]['DEPTH'], name=logs[j], line_color=colors[j]), row=1, col=log_cols[j])
            logplot.update_xaxes(type='log', row=1, col=log_cols[j], title_text=logs[j], tickfont_size=12, linecolor='#585858')
        else:
            logplot.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dataframe_well[wells[i]][logs[j]], y=dataframe_well[wells[i]]['DEPTH'], name=logs[j], line_color=colors[j]), row=1, col=log_cols[j])
            logplot.update_xaxes(col=log_cols[j], title_text=logs[j], linecolor='#585858')
    
    logplot.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True, ticks='inside', tickangle=45)
    logplot.update_yaxes(tickmode='linear', tick0=0, dtick=250, showline=True, linewidth=2, ticks='outside', mirror=True, linecolor='black')
    logplot.update_yaxes(row=1, col=1, autorange='reversed')
    logplot.update_layout(height=700, width=800, showlegend=False)
    logplot.update_layout(
                 title_text="Example of " + '<b>' + str(wells[i]) + '</b>', #Add a chart title
                 title_font_family="Arial",
                 title_font_size = 25, title_x=0.5)

    logplot.write_html('fig'+str(wells[i])+'.html') # the plot is automatically saved as html

    #list html plots to show what pop up folium should show on the map
    html_list.append('fig'+str(wells[i])+'.html')
```

and the resulted plot for the second iterate, which `Well 2F` **(overlapped image)**, is this

[image: Overlapping image]

the plot should be something like this **(non-overlapping image)**

[image: non-overlapping image]

`Well 2F` plot seems to be overlapped by `Well 1F` plot, which is the problem here must be the nested loop that I use for

Here is the dummy data if someone wanna try it

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DCnNpXpgqVCYNaMiD7FX6CpVqsOl3mkX?usp=share_link

Anyone has the idea how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I think the graphs overlap because they share the same y-axis, so I disable it. `shared_yaxes=False`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I just tried it, but it still overlap unfortunately @r-beginners

Comment: Do you have sample data you can present? Please paste it into the question. Based on that I will try your code.

Comment: I put my data on gdrive as csv, the link now in my edited question. Thank you for the reponse! @r-beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, if you want to plot using Plotly and for-looping it to make it automated multiple plot by only using single code run, you have to define it as a new function and loop through your defined function, and you must clear the plot content before turn into second loop, otherwise the second plot will be overlapped by first plot

in the first loop, put this before entering the second loop

```
logplot.data = []
```

here is the full code

```
def wellplot(wellx, title): #Update (defined function)
    for j in range(len(logs)):
        if j == 2: #change to log for RT
            logplot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=wellx[logs[j]], 
                y=wellx['DEPTH'], 
                name=logs[j], 
                line_color=colors[j]), 
                            row=1, col=log_cols[j])
            logplot.update_xaxes(type='log', row=1, col=log_cols[j], title_text=logs[j], tickfont_size=12, linecolor='#585858')
        else:
            logplot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=wellx[logs[j]],
                y=wellx['DEPTH'], 
                name=logs[j], 
                line_color=colors[j]), row=1, col=log_cols[j])
            logplot.update_xaxes(col=log_cols[j], title_text=logs[j], linecolor='#585858')

    logplot.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True, ticks='inside', tickangle=45)
    logplot.update_yaxes(tickmode='linear', tick0=0, dtick=250, showline=True, linewidth=2, ticks='outside', mirror=True, linecolor='black')
    logplot.update_yaxes(row=1, col=1, autorange='reversed')
    logplot.update_layout(height=700, width=700, showlegend=False)
    logplot.update_layout(
                title_text="Example of " + '<b>' + title + '</b>', #Add a chart title
                title_font_family="Arial",
                title_font_size = 25, title_x=0.5)
    
    logplot.write_html('fig'+title+'.html') # the plot is automatically saved as html
    #list html plots to show what pop up folium should show on the map
    html_list.append('fig'+title+'.html')
    logplot.show()

for i in range(len(wells)):
    logplot.data = [] #put this to clear the plot content (in order to make it non-overlapping)
    wellplot(dataframe_well[wells[i]], wells[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be caused by a problem with the log setting of the x-axis, so the log setting of the x-axis was set in a single row.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

logplot = make_subplots(rows=1,
                        cols=len(logs),
                        shared_yaxes = False,
                        #specs=[[{},{},{},{},{},{}]], 
                        horizontal_spacing=0.08,
                        vertical_spacing=0.08
                       )

for i in range(len(wells)):
    for j in range(len(logs)):
        logplot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=dataframe_well[wells[i]][logs[j]],
            y=dataframe_well[wells[i]]['DEPTH'],
            name=logs[j],
            line_color=colors[j]),
                          row=1, col=log_cols[j])

        logplot.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True, ticks='inside', tickangle=45)
        logplot.update_yaxes(tickmode='linear', tick0=0, dtick=250, showline=True, linewidth=2, ticks='outside', mirror=True, linecolor='black')
        logplot.update_yaxes(row=1, col=1, autorange='reversed')
        logplot.update_layout(height=700, width=800, showlegend=False)
        logplot.update_layout(
                     title_text="Example of " + '<b>' + str(wells[i]) + '</b>', #Add a chart title
                     title_font_family="Arial",
                     title_font_size = 25, title_x=0.5)
        logplot.update_layout(xaxis3=dict(type='log')) # update
        logplot.write_html('fig'+str(wells[i])+'.html') # the plot is automatically saved as html

        #list html plots to show what pop up folium should show on the map
    html_list.append('fig'+str(wells[i])+'.html')
    logplot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for trying to answer my question, I did have tried your solution, but it seems like the nested loop doesn't loop like it should be, the plot only produce 'Well 1F', have you opened the second plot in HTML? did you get the same result like me? because I got the same result between plot 1 and plot 2, only 'Well 1F'

Comment: When I checked the contents of the final list, there were 12 html file names where there should have been 2. I changed the indentation to add to the list.

Comment: I dont know about you, but mine still overlap between plot 1 and plot 2 for the second plot, which is in 'Well 2F', it seems like the problem is not the log setting

Comment: Your code saves the 6 column graph to an html format file twice and finally stores the html file name in a list. Am I understanding this correctly, or is the purpose of the 2 rows by 6 columns graph?

Comment: Please check the sequence of data acquisition, graph creation, and html file creation in the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bmNpKSTXwK9EqFaZn4jOlnOQP1cV4vMA?usp=sharing) environment. Please try to run this same thing in your environment. Your comments will disable this link.

Comment: here I give you the link that you are still got overlapped image [comparison between your plot and unoverlapped plot](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1DCnNpXpgqVCYNaMiD7FX6CpVqsOl3mkX) I put the image on the same gdrive as the data that I uploaded

Comment: Set up y-axis sharing and disabled y-axis reverse order, check Colab.

Comment: still produced overlapping image

Comment: Colab was restored to its original state. Unshare the y-axis in your code, change the horizontal spacing, and see if all the y-axes are the same. If the data is the same, then the remaining y-axis scale is suspect.

Comment: alright dude, thanks for the help, I appreciate it very much

Comment: What was the cause? Is this the end?

Comment: I still dont know dude, I try your advice, unshare the y-axis, changing horizontal spacing, unreverse the y-axis, even I tried to change the data with the other data, but still plot 1 overlaps plot 2. Maybe plotly has a bug in nested for-loop, I dont know dude

Comment: So it's still not improved. This will be my last comment, but my environment is the latest version, 5.13.0. What version are you using?

Comment: same like you, 5.13.0

Comment: hey, I just want to give you an update, it seems like Plotly give a bug when you try to plot in nested for-loop, the alternative way is, you have to make defined function by yourself and then looping it through your function